# Using array parameters in the Eclipse HibernateTools plugin

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, ide

How can I bind an array parameter in the HQL editor of the HibernateTools plugin?
The query parameter type list does not include arrays or collections.

For example:
     `Select * from Foo f where f.a in (:listOfValues)`.
How can I bind an array to that listOfValues?

Comment: Could you please provide an example query for which you would like to pass an array/collection?

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot. Hibernate replaces the objects it gets out of the database with it's own objects (kind of proxies). I would strongly assume Hibernate cannot do that with an array. So if you want to bind the array-data put it into a List on access by Hibernate.

As an example one could do:

```
select * from Foo f where f.a in f.list
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have already got the answer for this but for anyone else viewing this.  it appears that the HQL editor for hibernate tools does not support querying collections.  you whould have to not use the parameter and hard code it while testing in the Hibernate Tools HQL editor

```
Select * from Foo f where f.a in (123,1234)
```

The change the query back to what boutta posted when you put it back in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass a list to a HQL query.  I am not familiar with HQL editor... we are from the Nhibernate world.

```
select * from Foo f where f.a in (:foolist)

query.SetParameterList("foolist", list)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hibernate perspective]

In the hibernate perspective, you could see on the left side you can see left panel to enter query parameter, when you enter the :variable in the field and run the query you will get the result